# EE3 DevDemon Channel Images fatal error when trying to render template

Tags: devdemon, channel-images, ee3, fatal

ExpressionEngine 3.1.2

Channel Images  6.0.1

The addon installed ok. I have tried uninstalling and re-installing and had no change. The field was created ok. The location check passed. However, when I try to view the template, I just get 2 warnings and a fatal error.

[image: Test Location Results]

I understand that it says

> Even if all tests PASS, uploading can still fail due Apache/htaccess
>   misconfiguration

but I don't see anything wrong with either.

I am able to create an entry and upload the photos. I can see the images on the server. When I try to render a template, I get the following warnings and then fatal error:

[image]

Warning 1:

> Warning
>
> require(/home/stkhomes/system/user/addons/channel_images/locations//.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> user/addons/channel_images/models/channel_images_model.php, line 701
>   hide details
>
> Severity: E_WARNING

Warning 2:

> Warning
>
> require(/home/stkhomes/system/user/addons/channel_images/locations//.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> user/addons/channel_images/models/channel_images_model.php, line 701
>   hide details
>
> Severity: E_WARNING

Fatal Error:

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/stkhomes/system/user/addons/channel_images/locations//.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php56/pear') in
>   /home/stkhomes/system/user/addons/channel_images/models/channel_images_model.php
>   on line 701

I stepped through things and it appeared that the cache was not being written and returned inside the CI model.php file.

Does anyone have any insight on this? I am on a deadline and this is a huge snag for me right now as I planned the site around this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK,

Here is the last email to Himanshu with DevDemon support...

> Hi Brian
>
> Ok I have found the problem from your side . You have not set
>   Caching driver disable but to work with Channel Images, you must set
>   it to the "FIle". Now I have set it to file and it working perfectly.
>   I have set dummy Channel , Field Group and Field to test on your
>   server.
>
> I have attached image to display the setting
>
> thanks,
>
> Himanshu
>
> ---
>
> Himanshu,
>
> Thank you for finding this. I have two quick questions.
>
> 1)    I didn’t change anything on the cache settings. This was a blank
>   install and then started loading things in. Is this a default setting
>   for EE3 or could an addon have made that setting?
>
> 2)    If this is a
>   setting that has to be set proper for CI to work, should the addon
>   either inform or lock this setting in EE’s CP? If not, should this be
>   in the docs or at least issue a better error message?
>
> Thanks,
>
> Brian

Here is the image he attached...

[image: Settings]

Comment: This solution worked for me when I was getting the same error message. It would be nice if this apparently crucial step were mentioned in the documentation.